# Deprecated packages Tailwindcss when using create-nuxt-app

Tags: nuxt.js, tailwind-css

I've tried creating an app all using Tailwindcss, I have the following errors though:

I am using https://github.com/nuxt-community/create-nuxt-app to generate the app.

```
[1/4]   Resolving packages...
warning nuxt > postcss-cssnext@3.1.0: 'postcss-cssnext' has been deprecated in favor of 'postcss-preset-env'. Read more at https://moox.io/blog/deprecating-cssnext/
warning nuxt > webpack-bundle-analyzer > bfj-node4@5.3.1: Switch to the `bfj` package for fixes and new features!
```

I have tried replacing the packages but I get

```
✗ yarn remove postcss-cssnext
yarn remove v1.3.2
[1/2] Removing module postcss-cssnext...
error This module isn't specified in a manifest.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/remove for documentation about this command.
```

I can install the new packages but not remove them.

<sub>*This question is available on [Nuxt](https://cmty.app/nuxt) community ([#c48](https://cmty.app/nuxt/create-nuxt-app/issues/c48))*</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, These `deprecated` packages are dependencies of Tailwind's postcss toolchain. **You cannot remove a packages dependencies**, without removing that package itself. This is a feature, not a bug and should be that way. Otherwise, stuff would break in unimaginable ways.

Secondly, updating their own dependencies is the worry of the developers of the packages you choose to use (in this case. Tailwind's Adam Wathan). This is not something you should do, The developers will update their dependencies, and release a new version, when they have confirmed everything still works. This is again, to stop breakage.

And thirdly, there's no reason to panic, as the messages clearly just state "warning". Leave it as is, and everything will still work.